# Performing arithmetics with execve from arguments passed by terminal

Tags: c, bash, environment-variables, sh, execve

Trying to understand how to perform an arithmetic operation from arguments passed from terminal and use them in execve ?

```
./myProgram 'echo "$1+$2=$(($1+$2))"' 3 5
```

this is suppose to give me an output of 8

> what i've tried manually without argv :

```
pid_t pid;
char *parmList[] = {"sh", "-c", "echo $0 $1 + $2 1 2", NULL};
char *envParms[3] = {"1=1", "2=2", NULL};

if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    perror("fork error");
else if (pid == 0)
{
    execve("/bin/sh", parmList, envParms);
    printf("Return not expected. Must be an execve error.n");
}
```

i get the $0 which is sh ✅

but $1 and $2 are not recognized ...what i am missing ?

Comment: In the shell `$1` is *not* the environment variable `1`. It is the first positional parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to be passing 1 and 2 in the environment.  The shell wants them as positional parameters.  So you could do:

```
char *parmList[] = {"sh", "-c", "echo $0 $1 + $2 1 2", "sh", "1", "2", NULL};
```

Comment: thank you so much, i've been stock on this for days ‍♂️